# Getting started with Hyperledger-Fabric-Java-SDK

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Can anybody share the link for the documentation regarding Fabric-Java-SDK In other words suggest me how to start writing java code for Hyperledger-Fabric for invoking the chaincode and querying the chaincode

Answer (score 4):

Currently Java SDK is under development and should be released at some point, meanwhile you can start with here is the dependencies required for maven project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>fabric-sdk-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.55</version>
</dependency>
```

Next might want to take a look on the [unit-tests](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric) which are good references on how to start. Moreover there is [Rocket.Chat](http://chat.hypelrdger.org) channel for [#fabric-java-sdk](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java).

Also on [github mirror](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) of the project there is a readme have nice wall through as well.